# Onclick Selection Passing Incorrect Value From HTML Elements Generated in For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onclick

As the title says, my onclick event keeps passing the incorrect value - when there is more than one selection displayed, it passes the first and not the selected one. Here's my relevent code.

```
// my objects
var a = {id:101,name:'John Smith',age:42};
var b = {id:102,name:'Greg Jones',age:40};
var c = {id:103, name:'Clyde Barnes',age:36};
var d = {id:104,name:'John Smith',age:51};
var e = {id:105,name:'Sam Owens',age:40};
var f = {id:106, name:'John Smith',age:36};

// stored as an array
var personIndex = [a, b, c, d, e, f];

// my search function - I pass the value from an html form
function searchName(name) {
    'use strict';
    var nameMatch = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i <  personIndex.length; i++){
        if(name==personIndex[i].name){
            nameMatch.push(i);
        }
    }
    return nameMatch;
}
```

So having returned the value(s), I then display a list with buttons below and allow the user to select from many matches. The selected match should pass the index value as a cookie (which I am using an alert to test):

```
var y ='';
function displayDetail(value){
    alert(value); // here is where I would pass the value
}

function displayResult(x){
    U.$('results').innerHTML=x;
}

(function(){
    'use strict';
    var cookie = COOKIE.getCookie('nameIndex');
    var c = [];
    c = cookie.split('|');
    for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){ 
        var x='<br>Id: ' + personindex[c[i]].id + 
            'Name: ' + personindex[c[i]].name + 
            'Age: ' + personindex[c[i]].age + 
            ' <button id=' + c[i] + ' value=' + c[i] + '  onclick=displayDetail(' + c[i] + ')>Details</button>';
        y += x;
    }
    displayResult(y);
})();
```

What happens is this: I search for John Smith, it displays three John Smiths with buttons for each. I select the second one and it passes the value of the first one. If I select the third, it still passes the value of the first one. Can someone show me where I'm going wrong at?

Comment: Your search function code looks like it will only match one value unless you have duplicates (which you do); you're comparing the full name. It also doesn't split or otherwise look like it will work for two names, either. This might be the problem? Can you post the code for the click event, where is this happening? Or even better a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: The onclick event is in the anonymous function at the bottom of the code; what is happening is I am getting the full name from the search form, passing it to the search function, which returns in an array for multiple returns. No problem so far. When I loop through the array to create the list of returns, the buttons (with their onclick events) generated by the loop all wind up referencing only the first return. Does that make sense?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that actually calls searchName() and works with its result, though. Issue could be there where you actually set the cookie.

Comment: Also as I mentioned your searchName function can't possibly return two different names - it matches the full name. So if it returns an array of two "John Smith" strings, then displayDetail will sort of look the same - age and id will be different - but only depending on the logic in the code that sets the cookies. However, you haven't posted the code that uses the result of searchName and sets the cookie to the actual person (full name, age, etc). I suspect your issue is in that code. Can you post it?